# Is it possible to cache a specific value on mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to temporarily cache a specific value in a query to mysql with over 1000 results and different values​​, although some repeated?...

Here I show you an idea:

```
SELECT
    members.name,
    members.lastname,
    use_cache_if_it_was_consulted(SELECT countries.name FROM countries WHERE countries.id = members.country LIMIT 1) AS 'country'
FROM members
WHERE
    members.enable = 1
    AND members.gender = "M"
    AND members.country IN( 1, 2, 3 , 4 , 5 , 9 , 15 , 2342 , 234 )
```

Many "members" are from the U.S., other than Canada, and many others, from other countries.

The idea is that MySQL does not overload with subqueries, since I have a table ("members") with more than three million rows.

Comment: What issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to cache anything here.  You've got 3m members.. so?  A bigger question is whether there is the need for the subselect at all.  Do you have multiple countries with the same ID?  If not, get rid of the subselect and do a join.  If you have members with no country id, make it an outer join.  MySql ought to be fast enough to handle this just fine.

Comment: You can cache the result in php, but why do you want to do that?

Comment: Just a question. I want to know if it is possible to store information in cache, not to query again and again.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is not about caching a value in MySQL but to give other ideas and it is too big to put into a comment :

If you are using a subquery , you can use Join instead .

```
SELECT
    members.name,
    members.lastname,
    countries.name
FROM
    members
    LEFT OUTER JOIN countries ON countries.id = members.country
WHERE
        members.enable = 1
    AND members.gender = 'M'
    AND members.country IN( 1, 2, 3 , 4 , 5 , 9 , 15 , 2342 , 234 )
```

Considering country names are not something that usually change , you could also use a PHP array to store the Country Names with Country Id as key . Ex. `$countryNames` .

In which case , in the SQL you would retrieve country id :

```
SELECT
    members.name,
    members.lastname,
    members.country
```

When using it , you would use it as `$countryNames[id]` .

You can still have the countries table in the database . It is because there could be times that joining country table might be more appropriate . If you go this path , you would need to consider one as master and sync the other when there are any additions/modifications .

Hope this is useful .

Comment: Well, countries are just an example. Thanks anyway